# Scriptaculous "Sortable.create()" method does not work after making AJAX call to update unordered list

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, prototypejs, scriptaculous

This is my first stackoverflow post after about two years of using the site, so please don't release the hounds.

I am attempting to create the "edit my profile photos" section of a website, where a user can (1) add profile photos; (2) delete profile photos; and (3) reorder her profile photos.

From a database perspective, each user is limited to five profile pictures.  Therefore, my users table has fields for image0, image1, image2, image3, and image4.

Adding photos is straightforward, but I have run into a curious issue when deleting and reordering photos.

To reorder the photos, I have made use of the prototype/scriptaculous "sortable.create()" method.  Specifically, I display each photo within a list element of an 
   unordered list.

Reordering any list element will then make an ajax call, and in the corresponding php script I reorder the images appropriately (e.g., what used to be image0 will
   now be written in the database to image2, etc.).

I then recreate as HTML the updated unordered list of images.

Finally, in the handling ajax javascript function (i.e., if the ajax.status == 200 and ajax.readyState == 4),
   I call the sortable.create method to once again make the new unordered list of images sortable.

The aforementioned works absolutely fine.  Now here's the brainteaser:

Each list element in the unordered list also contains a link to delete the particular image in question.
   So imagine a list of photos, each with a "delete this photo" link under every photo in the unordered list.

Here's a rough sketch of what the HTML looks like:

```
  <ul id="profile_pics" onmouseup="reorder_photos();">
     <li id="0"><img src="images/image0.jpg"><a href="?delete_id=0" onclick="return false;" onmouseup="stopPropagation(event); delete_photo('image0');">delete this photo</a></li>
     <li id="1"><img src="images/image1.jpg"><a href="?delete_id=1" onclick="return false;" onmouseup="stopPropagation(event); delete_photo('image1');">delete this photo</a></li>
     <li id="2"><img src="images/image2.jpg"><a href="?delete_id=2" onclick="return false;" onmouseup="stopPropagation(event); delete_photo('image2');">delete this photo</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Note that clicking the "delete this photo" link will call the delete_photo function, but will NOT implicate the reorder_photos function because of the call to the stopPropagation() function.

The delete_photo function makes an AJAX call to a PHP script that (1) deletes the photo in question, (2) makes the appropriate database adjustments, and (3) recreates the unordered list.  The ajax handling function then calls sortable.create()
   to make this new unordered list sortable.

The problem is that the new unordered list IS NOT SORTABLE.

What makes the issue more bizarre and confounding is that when I call another scriptaculous method like "$('profile_pics').fade({ duration: 2.5 });" in the ajax handling function, that DOES work.

Why?  Why?  Why?

Any help would be infinitely appreciated.  If sample code would help, I can post that -- I just didn't want to make this post more encyclopedic than it already is.

Answer (score 1):

When content is replaced on a page, the event handlers go with them. You need to re-initialize your sortable after your AJAX call.

Comment: Hi diodeus,  Thanks for the reply.  I did indeed add the event handlers in the new HTML, and then called sortable.create() in the handling ajax function.  The sortable.create() won't work, but when I tried something else like making the unordered list fadeable, that did work.  Does that help?  I can post code if that would assist.  Thanks again for your reply, this has been driving me crazy for the past week.

Comment: You may have to destroy the original sortable first.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that -- making a call to Sortable.destroy(), and then attempted Sortable.create().  Thanks again, though.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this will invoke the ire of the community, but is there a way to "hire" someone on this site to look at this stuff?  I really need this taken care of and wouldn't mind shelling out the cash.  The fundamental issue can be reduced to maybe 200 lines of code, max. **Hopes lightning bolts don't strike**

Comment: I realize this is over a year old, and... there's a bounty system now to handle this secondary question you asked.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work